# List pass by reference confusion in Python

Tags: python, list, reference

I have this snippet of code that just sorts a list of numbers that are guaranteed to be between 0 and R-1 (inclusive). The following code does the sort correctly but I don't understand why the input passed in remains unmodified.

```
def bucket(arr, R):
    assert type(arr) is list
    for i in arr:
        assert i >=0 and i < R
    b = [0] * R
    for i in arr:
        b[i]+=1
    arr = []
    for ind, v in enumerate(b):
        arr = arr + [ind] * v
    print(arr)
```

Why is `inp` in this example unchanged after the function has been called:

```
>>> inp
[3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5]
>>> bucket(inp, 8)
[1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> inp # unchanged, why?
[3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Pass by reference semantics *are not supported in python*.

Comment: Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you create a new variable called `arr` in the line `arr = []` and from this point on you operate on a new list. Similarly you always create new lists inside the following `for`-loop with the `arr = arr + [ind] * v` operations.

You could simply change it to:

```
def bucket(arr, R):
    assert type(arr) is list
    for i in arr:
        assert i >= 0 and i < R
    b = [0] * R
    for i in arr:
        b[i] += 1
    arr[:] = []  # remove all items from the list (in-place)
    for ind, v in enumerate(b):
        arr.extend([ind] * v)  # extend the list in-place, you could also use "arr += [ind] * v"
    print(arr)
```

Example:

```
>>> inp = [3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5]
>>> bucket(inp, 8)
[1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> inp
[1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: @johnktejik Do you have any specific question about the code? I copied most of it from the question, so I didn't include any explanations for the copied parts, but if you have a specific question I'll try to explain it. But if you have problems with the code in general you probably should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning `[]` to `arr` you are losing the reference to the existing array, and creating a new one.

To change it, you could use

```
inp.sort()
```

[More info on sort vs sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Python passes by assignment, and the semantics are extremely similar to Java's pass by value.

The confusion arises because you are passing the *pointer* by value. This means you cannot modify the pointer inside the function, but no one can stop you from modifying what the pointer is *pointing to* (i.e. the data) So, for example:

```
x = 3
def change_x(x):
    x = 5
    return x
change_x(x)
print x
# Outputs 3
```

The value of x outside the function (in this case, 3) was copied before x entered the function, so the assignment does nothing. This is typically what we expect when we hear pass by value.

```
x = [1,2,3]
print(id(x))
# Outputs some "address"
def change_x(x):
    x.clear()
    x.extend([4,5,6])
    print(id(x))
    # Outputs the SAME address as above
    return x
change_x(x)
print(x)
# Outputs [4,5,6]
```

What the heck. I thought we just said we couldn't change x. The catch is we didn't change x! We just changed the data x is pointing to (there is a subtle, but important difference here). x is still the same pointer. Note that the addresses output by `id` are the same.

```
x = [1,2,3]
print(id(x))
# Outputs some "address"
def change_x(x):
    x = [4,5,6]
    print(id(x))
    # Outputs some DIFFERENT "address". The pointer to x was changed (inside this function).
    return x
change_x(x)
print(x)
# Outputs [1,2,3]
```

It copied the value of x before it was passed in (the pointer value, not the data, was copied). So, again, reassignment does nothing. Note that the `id` function outputs *different* values this time. So after the function returns, we get the original value of x (the original value of the pointer, that is)